# Music Not Playing - XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio

I have this code to play sounds:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"audio2", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

It works fine for an audio file that I have that is about 1 second long. It does not, however, work for one of my files that is about 4 minutes long. How can I fix this? They're both mp3 files and placed in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound), `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` has a limits as below:

```
Sound files that you play using this function must be:

- No longer than 30 seconds in duration
```

You can use `AVAudioPlayer` instead.